# Can't scrape all data on a page because Js script adds data as you scroll down

Tags: php, xpath, web-scraping, load

I need to scrape data using PHP as a constraint. I use file_get_contents() to get the HTML from a page and xpath to reach the data I want to get.

Everything is working fine except for one thing: the page I'm scraping data from use some Js script that is injecting more data as you scroll the page down.

So when I get the HTML from this page, I can only access the content it has before you scroll down.

Is there a way I can scrape ALL the content of this page in PHP ?

The Js script looks like this :

```
 $(document).ready(function()
        {
            var load = false;
            var offset = 25;
            var limit = 24;
            var order = "town";
            var types = ["garage"];

            if(offset >= total)
                $('#info_display_results').remove();

            $(window).data('ajaxready', true);

            $(window).scroll(function()
            {
                if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) > $(document).height() - 300
                    && offset < total
                    && load == false)
                {
                    $(window).data('ajaxready', false);
                    load = true;
                    $('#loading').fadeIn(800);

                    $.get('/geoloc/list', {'types[0]': types[0], 'offset':offset, 'limit':limit, 'deptNumber': dept, 'order':order}, function(data)
                    {
                        if (data != '')
                        {
                            $('#content').append(data);
                            offset+= limit;

                            $(window).data('ajaxready', true);
                            load = false;
                            $('#loading').hide();
                        }

                        console.log(offset);
                        console.log(total);

                        if(offset >= total)
                            $('#info_display_results').addClass('hidden');
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Really interested in this. I get the point of asynchronous loading, but it makes it incredibly hard to do seemingly trivial stuff like scraping a web page. Sometimes it's easy because the page you're trying to scrape uses a public API that you can just talk to. But more often than not, they don't.